# How to avoid the white space under the html page for the height and width 768×1024?

Tags: html, css, responsive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

This is the css code im using for html page.

Comment: your code is totally wrong.. you are not targeting any class/element in your css.. share more code what are you trying..

Comment: you should apply this html on body.

Comment: like this.... @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
body{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

like in the comments try:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
}
```

you assign these styles to the whole body of your page in the range of  768px to 1024px.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are trying...

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="kittens.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0%;
  }
}
```

However, this does not make the image full-screen, as I assume you want. It makes the image responsive and fully visible though. To make the image fill the entire screen you should make the image a background-image in CSS. Leave out the image tag , like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And use this CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background: url('kittens.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    bakcground-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Good luck!